# Manifest does not load when redirecting with middleware Next JS

Tags: next.js, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I have already made a couple of pwa projects with Next JS but this time my site.webmanifest file does not load. When I look at the site.webmanifest in the browser I see it loads an html file with the starting page.

site.webmanifest:

```
{
  "name": "Task Manager",
  "short_name": "Task Manager",
  "description": "Application to save tasks",
  "display": "standalone",
  "start_url": "/",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/icons/manifest-icon-192.maskable.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "/icons/manifest-icon-192.maskable.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable"
    },
    {
      "src": "/icons/manifest-icon-512.maskable.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "/icons/manifest-icon-512.maskable.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable"
    }
  ]
}
```

_middleware.tsx:

```
import { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function middleware(req: NextRequest, event: NextFetchEvent) {
  const jwt = req.cookies["jwt"];
  const urlArray: Array<string> = req.url.split("/");
  const baseUrl = `${urlArray[0]}//${urlArray[2]}`;
  if (req.url !== `${baseUrl}/login` && !jwt) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(`${baseUrl}/login`);
  }
}
```

link to manifest in _document.tsx

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest" />
```

Error: [Error on browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07BgX.png)

EDIT: I found out that this error happens because I use middleware to redirect to the login page when unauthenticated. But I still don't have a solution for this problem because I want to keep the middleware.

Comment: Do you have any redirects setup in your Next.js app?

Comment: Where do you have site.webmanifest file?

Comment: @juliomalves I found out that the reason for the error is because I use middleware to redirect to the login page when unauthenticated. Do you have an idea how to fix this error while keeping the middleware as it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the possible issue, i was having the same problem.

Next.js Middleware in the pages/_middleware.ts intercepts all the requests made, even those made to "public/images" or in your case /site.webmanifest

Your middleware tells that any request needs to have a jwt or be /login, so this middleware blocks the request made for /site.webmanifest

Still don't know if this is intended by Nextjs

```
if ((req.url !== `${baseUrl}/login` || req.url !== '/site.webmanifest') && !jwt) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(`${baseUrl}/login`);
}
```

Add something like private routes so the middleware only blocks request to them

```
const privatePaths = [/\/privateRoute2/,/\/privateRoute1\/*/]
const isPrivate = privatePaths.some(rx => rx.test(req.nextUrl.pathname));
if (isPrivate && !jwt) {
    const url = req.nextUrl.clone()
    url.pathname = '/authenticate'
    return NextResponse.redirect(url, 302);
}
return NextResponse.next()
```

Answer (score 0):

Great answer @Santiago,

True, the nextjs [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware) is new and is currently beta. It basically intercepts all your routes including your assets files served from the pubic/ folder. The simplest way to solve this is to actually make sure files with extensions are excluded (i.e .png, .jpg, .manifest, .json, etc)

```
const PUBLIC_FILE = /\.(.*)$/;
const isPublicFiles = PUBLIC_FILE.test(req.nextUrl.pathname);
if (!jwt && !isPublicFiles) {
  const token = await auth.currentUser?.getIdToken();
  const url = req.nextUrl.clone();
  url.pathname = '/login';

  return NextResponse.redirect(url);
}
return NextResponse.next();
```