# Build Next.js app before deploying via Serverless Component

Tags: next.js, serverless

We're using the Next.js Serverless Component from: https://serverless-nextjs.com/ to deploy our Next.js app to AWS using the Serverless framework.

It takes around 7-8 mins for the app to be built and then deployed to AWS.

We were hoping to instead build the app up-front and then deploy the pre-built code...

You can tell Serverless to not build and just do the deployment with `build.enabled: false`:

```
# serverless.yml

myNextApplication:
  component: "@sls-next/serverless-component@3.7.0"
  inputs:
    bucketName: our-bucket-name
    build:
      enabled: false
```

However when we run `yarn next build` the app is built under `./next`.

When serverless builds the app it stores the state in `.stateless` and the files in `.stateless_nextjs`. So therefore the next build isn't compatible with deploying a prebuilt app...

This means if we try and build the app and then call serverless after we get the following error:

`myNextApplication › Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/cameron/Projects/nextjs-serverless/.serverless_nextjs/default-lambda/manifest.json'`

So how do you build the app first and then deploy the build using Next.js Serverless Component?

Versions:

```
"dependencies": {
  "next": "12.2.2",
  "react": "18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "18.2.0",
  "serverless": "2.72.2"
},

component: "@sls-next/serverless-component@3.7.0"
```

Comment: What's your package versions? and that of nextjs?

Comment: [Custom build directory](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/setting-a-custom-build-directory) in NextJS? Or missing a [nextConfigDir](https://github.com/serverless-nextjs/serverless-next.js#inputs) in serverless config?

Answer (score 0):

**The reason is probably wrong next.js middleware setup.** `manifest.json` is built upon simulated requests that goes through nextjs middlewares. please refer to this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71753616/9292770).

nextjs middleware had some [structural changes](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/middleware-upgrade-guide) around `v12.x` that requires migration. it's hard to figure out what's wrong because it gives little or no warning messages and it builds okay. I had similar issues too.

## Solution

- check if your deploy includes proper package lock file(`yarn.lock, package-lock.json...`) so that fixed version of `next.js` is included when deploying.
- check [latest middleware examples](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples) from github repo and try match middleware file structure and code.
- check out [nextjs middleware migration guide](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/middleware-upgrade-guide) mentioned earlier; try build in local environment and make sure `manifest.json` is created.

Comment: The reason the `manifest.json` file isn't present is because Next.js builds to `.next` and the Next.js Serverless Component builds to `.serverless_nextjs` so the build command the the component are not compatible with one another... or so it seems... so it's not clear how you'd build up-front...

Comment: @Cameron sorry I had not catched that by the time I was writing it. I'll fix the answer